# How to include jquery plugin validation in Yii framework?

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins, yii

my code in view 
what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/javascript/form.js');
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/javascript/validate.js');
?>
<div class="letter">
    <h3>или напишите нам письмо!</h3>
    <form class="contact-form">
        <p>
            <label for="name">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Почта</label>
            <input type="text" id="email">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="message">Сообщение</label>
            <textarea id="message"></textarea>
        </p>
        <button class="send">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.contact-form').validate();
    });
</script>
```

sorry for my english, need help, I'm trying to connect a validation of the plugins, I do not use CHhtml and CActiveForm

Comment: Why don't you use CActiveForm? It has built-in client-side + server-side validation support based on model rules

Comment: Why are u not using CActive form ??

Comment: okay, I'll use CActiveForm

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl."/javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl."/javascript/form.js");
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl."/javascript/validate.js");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My tip:
       use `Yii :: app () -> getBaseUrl (true)`, `Yii :: app () -> getBaseUrl ()` can cause problems when deploying an application.